# Secure access to part of properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

In my application I have two roles (`admin` and `normal`). In model I have class (example):

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Extra { get; set; }
}
```

Users can also edit that objects and use filters to search. Application is based on WebAPI ASP.NET Core with EF Core.

There is a requirement that `normal` should not see (or do anything with it) `Extra` property. Should I protect the data everywhere in application ( services, controllers, data access layer) by splitting model class (or something else) or just format output of endpoints by ignoring properties?

One of my ideas is to create an attribute, put it on `Extra` property and then, using `ContractResolver` ignoring properties with that attribute when user is not eligible to see that property. Also modify EF change tracker to ignore saving that property (in same cases).

Is there any pattern or strategy how to handle with that problem?

Comment: Sounds like you need to abstract your class out into multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in mechanism for this, no, because it's far too granular. Also, trying to enforce this at the EF level would mean leaking your HttpContext into your DAL, which is a bad idea for a number of reasons.

My best recommendation would be to model it with inheritance. In other words, create something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ExtraFoo : Foo
{
    public string Extra { get; set; }
}
```

By default, Entity Framework will implement this via single-table inheritance, so your backing table will look pretty much exactly the same. However, this then gives you the ability to work with one or the other separately.

Then, I would recommend employing completely separate controllers and/or actions for working with each type. This allows you employ different authorization for each, ensuring that "normal" users will only ever be able to work with `Foo` (rather than `ExtraFoo`). To negate the obvious duplication this would imply, you can employ a base controller utilizing generics that each type-specific controller could then inherit from:

```
public class BaseFooController<TFoo> : Controller
    where TFoo : Foo, new()
{
    // all your actions here, utilizing generic type, e.g.:

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TFoo foo)
    {
        ...
    }
}

[Authorize(Roles = "normal")]
public class FooController : BaseFooController<Foo>
{
}

[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class ExtraFooController : BaseFooController<ExtraFoo>
{
}
```

Comment: I try to avoid splitting model class into two because `Foo` cannot exists separately. Each object should have type `ExtraFoo` and `Foo` is some kind of view for that object. Will it be a better idea to use the interfaces?